# Alpinejs smooth nested accordions

Tags: alpine.js

I want to create smooth nested accordions with Alpinejs.
My problem is that to have a smooth animation, the parent accordion calculates its max-height compared to the children. Except that the children are not unrolled when max-height is calculated, so when we unroll the sub accordions, some elements are hidden because of parent accordion max-height. I don't know if i'm clear.

I recreate the issue on codepen, can someone help me with that please ?

```
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/loicdls/pen/WNdQwpV)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the main accordion has the `overflow-hidden` class, so when a sub accordion opens, its content sometimes will be hidden. So we need to introduce a new variable, e.g. `hideOverflow` that switch off this class before we open a sub accordion. However we also need to switch back on the class if we want to close the main accordion.

```
<div class="w-8/12 my-4 mx-auto"
      x-data="{open: false, hideOverflow: true, selected: null}">
  <!-- Main toggle -->
  <div @click="selected = null; hideOverflow = true; open = !open"
       class="w-full cursor-pointer px-5 py-3 bg-indigo-800 text-white text-center inline-block">
    Main Accordion (toggle)
  </div>

  <!-- Accordion -->
  <div class="relative transition-all duration-700 max-h-0"
        x-ref="main"
        :class="hideOverflow && 'overflow-hidden'"
        x-bind:style="(open || selected) ? 'max-height: ' + $refs.main.scrollHeight + 'px' : ''">
    <div class="bg-gray-200">
      <!-- Sub 1 toggle -->
      <div @click="hideOverflow = false; selected !== 0 ? selected = 0 : selected = null"
          class="w-full cursor-pointer px-5 py-3 bg-indigo-600 text-white text-center inline-block">
        Sub Accordion 1 (toggle)
      </div>

      <!-- Sub 1 accordion -->
      <div class="relative overflow-hidden transition-all max-h-0 duration-700"
           x-ref="container0"
           x-bind:style="selected == 0 ? 'max-height: ' + $refs.container0.scrollHeight + 'px' : ''">
        Lorem<br> ipsum<br> dolor <br> sit <br> amet.
      </div>

      <!-- Sub 2 toggle -->
      <div @click="hideOverflow = false; selected !== 1 ? selected = 1 : selected = null"
           class="w-full cursor-pointer px-5 py-3 bg-indigo-600 text-white text-center inline-block">
        Sub Accordion 2 (toggle)
      </div>

      <!-- Sub 2 accordion -->
      <div class="relative overflow-hidden transition-all max-h-0 duration-700"
           x-ref="container1"
           x-bind:style="selected == 1 ? 'max-height: ' + $refs.container1.scrollHeight + 'px' : ''">
        Lorem<br> ipsum<br> dolor <br> sit <br> amet.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't seems to work :/. The subs accordions doesn't open, did I missed something ?

Comment: It's working for me. Did you copy my whole example or just parts of it?

Comment: I copy whole, can you share your codepen pls ?

Comment: Sure! [https://jsfiddle.net/yhard3b9/](https://jsfiddle.net/yhard3b9/)

Comment: It works, I didn't have the good version of Tailwind... Thank you very much !

Comment: I still have an issue, if I have a div under the accordion, the sub accordions exceed on the div because of the height of the main accordion. I would like  to have the sum of all subaccordions to define the max-height of the main (if its the right way), so instead of $refs.mainAccordion.scrollHeight, how can I have sum of all sub accordions ? I did some tests without success.

Comment: Or you may consider using AlpineJS `collapse` plugin -> https://alpinejs.dev/plugins/collapse

Comment: I will check for it thanks for all.